# Parsing an unfamiliar YAML/JSON file in Go

Tags: json, go, yaml

How do you parse YAML data, in Go, without knowing its structure in advance? All of the examples I've seen assume you want to decode a marshaled map whose keys you already know. What if you don't know the keys? What if it's not a map but a marshaled list, a scalar, or some other common type?

Though I'm principally concerned with YAML, here, it seems like the technique might be generally useful for JSON, etc.. since there's a general pattern for parsing structured data (tagged structs, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

For JSON, unmarshal the data to an `interface{}` value.  Use type assertions to determine what's in the value.

```
var v interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
switch v := v.(type) {
case string:
    fmt.Println("string:", v)
case float64: 
    fmt.Println("number:", v)
case []interface{}:
    fmt.Println("array:", v)
case map[string]interface{}:
    fmt.Println("object:", v)
case nil:
    fmt.Println("nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of JSON, the standard library `json.Unmarshal` function will unmarshal arbitrary JSON if you like, if you pass it a pointer to an uninitialized empty interface. (See [this example.](https://play.golang.org/p/LF08ITTxlQ))

The [official docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) even say as much:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> > bool, for JSON booleans
> >
> > float64, for JSON numbers
> >
> > string, for JSON strings
> >
> > []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> >
> > map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> >
> > nil for JSON null

---

**Edit:** Though not documented, the same is true of the [yaml](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal) package; I tested on my workstation, and passing in a pointer to an uninitialized empty interface results in the initialization of correct arrays, maps, and primitives.